# Why OrElseGet seems not to be called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lambda, java-8

I'm building a REST API with SpringBoot and decided to build it in SpringBoot last version.

The problem I am having, is that for some reason my code seems not to be reaching `OrElseGet`, or I'm not knowing how to deal with the `Optional` stuff.

What I want to do is return the status code `200` and the entity in case the object is found in the database, and status code `404` if not found.

However, when specifying an invalid code, I am getting the string `null` in the response body and the status code 200.

Here is my code:

```
@GetMapping("/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<Optional<Categoria>> searchByCode(@PathVariable Long codigo) {

    return Optional
            .ofNullable( categoriaRepository.findById(codigo) )
            .map(cat-> ResponseEntity.ok().body(cat))
            .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build()); 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how the example snippet compiles as it should return a `ResponseEntity<Optional<Categoria>>`.

Comment: I actually had to write `ResponseEntity<Optional<Categoria>>` instead of `ResponseEntity<Categoria>` to compile. Even though I was not happy with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few improvements that can be done here. Firstly why are you returning an `Optional` from your REST Controller. I don't see any point there. You can merely return the `Categoria` object instead and let jackson to serialize it into a json payload. So change the code as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{codigo}")
public ResponseEntity<Categoria> searchByCode(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
    return categoriaRepository.findById(codigo).map(cat -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(cat))
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

And here's the mock repository I used to simulate this.

```
public interface CategoriaRepository extends JpaRepository<Categoria, Integer>{
    default Optional<Categoria> findById(long codigo) {
        // return Optional.ofNullable(new Categoria(1, "name"));
        return Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }
}
```

Also wrapping the response inside of another `Optional` adds some complexity to your code while making it much harder to read too. This should give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, it really works. Can you tell me the difference between `Optional.ofNullable( categoriaRepository.findById(codigo)).map(cat-> ResponseEntity.ok().body(cat));` to `categoriaRepository.findById(codigo).map(cat -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(cat));` ? because the former doesn't even compile.

Comment: By the way, the reason I was returning an `Optional` was just because it wouldn't compile if I didn't do so. I know it doesn't make sense, but the Json response had my object in its body even though it was returning `Optional`, so I thought, why not? (bad idea right).

Comment: You said the former does not compile, but it does in my case? Anyway there's no point in returning an `Optional` from a rest end point. Your client may not be a Java client, rather some javascript client who consumes the response JSON payload. So just return the Object itself.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Do you think ResponseEntity.ok().body(cat) will return null in case of cat object is null? if not then you need to update it or explain how it's works?

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal There's nothing to explain. The code obviously returns `ResponseEntity.notFound().build()` if the `Categoria` instance is `null` so the end user gets 404 NOT FOUND error.