# Validating Nullable fields in Java

Tags: java, null, option-type, nullable, null-check

Let's say we have a class `Product` which has some *nullable* fields that are allowed to be null, for example, `quantityAvailable` and `quantityReserved`.

I may want to validate these fields and throw an error, but since they are allowed to be `null`, I have, firstly, to check for `null`:

```
if (product.getQuantityAvailable() != null && product.getQuantityReserved() != null) {
  if (product.getQuantityAvailable() < product.getQuantityReserved()) {
    System.out.println("Error");
  }
}
```

When you have many *nullable* fields and many *null-checks*, this becomes tedious. Even with `ofNullable` it doesn't get any better.

```
Optional.ofNullable(product.getQuantityAvailable())
    .ifPresent((available) -> {
          Optional.ofNullable(product.getQuantityReserved())
              .ifPresent((reserved) -> {
                    if (available < reserved) {
                      System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                  });
        });
```

Ideally there would exist some annotation that would check for nulls and skip if any were found, but obviously this wouldn't work.

```
if (@Nullable product.getQuantityAvailable() < @Nullable product.getQuantityReserved()) {
  System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Is there a solution to avoid the boilerplate above?

Comment: Here is a nice article that explains what you can do to avoid null checks: https://www.baeldung.com/java-avoid-null-check

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko there are no `Optional` fields here. I meant "optional" as in "not required", not the Java class. I explain this at the top of my post. The problem here is that some fields in my model are not required, and can be null in the database.

Comment: @BoškoBezik Hey I came across that article while searching but unfortunately that's for a different case where you want a value to actually not be null, whereas in my case null is allowed.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko You said "you make these fields `Optional` in the first place" in your other comment, not me. I never said I had `Optional` fields. This was something you said.

Comment: Your best option might be to use a language that has null-safety built in, such as Kotlin. That would allow you to write `product?.let { quantityAvailable > quantityRequired }`, which still has the same null check it's just easier to read and write.

Comment: @Rosa well in that case there is not much you can do. You will have to do a bunch of null checks.

Comment: @Rosa The title of the question and some phrases in it are confusing. It has to be **Nullable** instead of *Optional*. The phrase `optional properties` makes sense only in JavaScript, **not** in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there's nothing wrong with explicit *null-checks*.

Secondly, `Optional.ofNullable()` is **not** meant for validation. By hiding a *null-check* with it, you're obscuring what the code does and making it harder to read.

Here's a quote from the [*answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34458582/17949945) by *@StuartMarks*, Java and OpenJDK developer, regarding what `Optional` is meant to be used for:

> The ***primary use*** of `Optional` is as follows:
>
> Optional is intended to
> provide a limited mechanism for library ***method return types*** where
> there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null
> for that is overwhelmingly likely to cause errors.

> A typical **code smell** is, instead of the code using method chaining to
> handle an Optional returned from some method, it creates an `Optional`
> from something that's **nullable**, in order to chain methods and **avoid
> conditionals**.

Also have a look at this answer by *Stuart Marks* [*"Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048770/17949945).

Using `Optional.ofNullable()` to avoid *null-checks* is an **antipattern**. You shouldn't create `Optional` in order to validate an object that can be `null`

I see nothing that can be considered to be "bad" in this snippet from your question. Yes, it's verbose, it's a price for allowing *nullable* fields.

```
if (product.getQuantityAvailable() != null && product.getQuantityReserved() != null) {
    if (product.getQuantityAvailable() < product.getQuantityReserved()) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

If you want to reduce the level of nesting, here's a *null-safe* alternative with [`Objects.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#compare(T,T,java.util.Comparator)):

```
if (Objects.compare(product.getQuantityAvailable(), 
                    product.getQuantityReserved(), 
                    Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())) < 0) {
    // perform the required action
    throw new MyCustomException("a message helpful in debuging here");
}
```

When you have a lot of *nullable fields* in your objects, which you eventually expect to contain some values, *null-checks are inevitable.

Code clattered with *null-checks* can be difficult to read, but it doesn't imply that *null-checks* are the root of all evil. It's just the consequence of your design decisions.

If you want to reduce the number of *null-checks* in your code, then assign default values (`0` for `Integer`, `BigDecimal.ZERO`, empty collections, etc.) instead of keeping `null` references in every place where it doesn't harm the logic of the application.

***Sidenote:*** contrary to some languages like type TypeScript, in Java there's **no** notion of *optional properties*, which was initially mentioned in the title of the question. Practices that are suitable for one language aren't necessarily applicable in another. If you want to leverage Java to its full power, reproducing your experience with frontend languages isn't the right way to go.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I was on holiday. I have now accepted this answer.

Comment: Would you say that using `Optional` to do a null check when fetching data from a database is also an antipattern? For example, see the code in this question (ignore the method signature, just look at the return statement) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690886/why-orelseget-seems-not-to-be-called

Comment: @Rosa Using `Optional` to perform *null-checks* is an antipattern (it doesn't matter where the data comes from) as I said in the answer. Regarding the question you refer to - have a look at the [*answer to it*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51691096/17949945) (there's no misuse optional there).

Comment: @Rosa Also have a look at this question: [*"Should Optional.ofNullable() be used for null check?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038417/should-optional-ofnullable-be-used-for-null-check/52048770).

Comment: @Rosa You can use methods from the [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#method-summary) class like `requireNonNull()` to perform validation. They were designed specifically for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define models with default values for additional attributes instead of accept null value. Example, with an Integer attribute, default value is 0 and String attribute is empty string

Comment: I thought about that but sometimes a default value doesn't make sense, so you end up using values like 0 or -1 or INFINITY which is even worse because you have to check for those explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I would not discount `Optional`, `OptionalInt` and such, even if the persistent database column uses NULL.

Indeed it would be cumbersome:

```
product.getQuantityAvailable()
    .ifPresent((available) -> {
          product.getQuantityReserved()
              .ifPresent((reserved) -> {
                    if (available < reserved) {
                      System.out.println("Error");
                    }
                  });
        });
```

But with a map from OptionalInt to IntStream:

```
if (product.getQuantityAvailable()
        .map().anyMatch(av -> product.getQuantityReserved()
            .map.anyMatch(res -> av < res))) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

You could store the predicate lambdas separately, say in the product.

The code is more readable, less errorprone, though a bit )))-ish.

Comment: I guess having the lambdas elsewhere is a good idea, but I've just tried this and found these kind of condition checks were usually unique so I could not reuse them much. Thanks for the suggestion though I'll play with it.